# Create a rank with arithmetic math in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having trouble to do arithmetic math and store somewhere. 
I have to create a rank that is based on the games. If a country win get 3 points and if it is a draw win 1 point.

In the code there is 1 draw and 5 wins. How I sum the point from the countries?
Do I need the element  or I create an attribute or something else?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file:///C:/Users/Cesar%20Frantz/Desktop/teste.xsl"?>
<Bolaocopa xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/Users/Cesar%20Frantz/Desktop/teste.xsd">
    <grupos>
        <grupo tipo="A">
            <pais id="s1">Franca<pontos>0</pontos></pais>
            <pais id="s2">Senegal<pontos>0</pontos></pais>
            <pais id="s3">Uruguai<pontos>0</pontos></pais>
            <pais id="s4">Dinamarca<pontos>0</pontos></pais>
        </grupo>
    </grupos>
    <jogoGrupo id="a">
        <selecao paiscasa="s1" golc="1" paisfora="s2" golf="1"/>
        <selecao paiscasa="s3" golc="2" paisfora="s4" golf="3"/>
        <selecao paiscasa="s4" golc="4" paisfora="s2" golf="1"/>
        <selecao paiscasa="s3" golc="6" paisfora="s1" golf="3"/>
        <selecao paiscasa="s4" golc="8" paisfora="s1" golf="5"/>
        <selecao paiscasa="s2" golc="1" paisfora="s3" golf="7"/>
    </jogoGrupo>
</Bolaocopa>
```

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file:///C:/Users/Cesar%20Frantz/Desktop/teste.xsl"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                <xsl:template match="/Bolaocopa">                                   
                        <xsl:for-each select="/Bolaocopa/jogoGrupo[1]/selecao">                 
                        <xsl:variable name="paiscasa" select="@paiscasa" />
                        <xsl:variable name="paisfora" select="@paisfora" />                     
                        <xsl:variable name="contador"/>                                                                                                         
                        <xsl:if test="(@golc &gt; @golf)">
                            Vitoria::
                            <xsl:value-of select="/Bolaocopa/grupos/grupo/pais[@id = $paiscasa]"/>
                            <br/><br/>
                        </xsl:if>                       
                        <xsl:if test="(@golf &gt; @golc)">
                            Vitoria::
                            <xsl:value-of select="/Bolaocopa/grupos/grupo/pais[@id = $paisfora]"/>  
                            <br/><br/>                                                  
                        </xsl:if>               
                        <xsl:if test="(@golf = @golc)">
                            Empate::
                            <xsl:value-of select="/Bolaocopa/grupos/grupo/pais[@id = $paiscasa]"/>
                            e <xsl:value-of select="/Bolaocopa/grupos/grupo/pais[@id = $paisfora]"/>                            
                            <br/><br/>                      
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:template>                             
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by XMLSpy v2013 sp1 (x64) (http://www.altova.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="T_pontos">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:enumeration value="0"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="AT_7">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="A"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="AT_5">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="5"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="7"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="AT_3">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:enumeration value="0"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="4"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="6"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="8"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="AT_2">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="s1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="s2"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="s3"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="s4"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="AT_1">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="a"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="T_selecao">
        <xs:attribute ref="paisfora" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="paiscasa" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="golf" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="golc" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="T_pais" mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="pontos"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="AT_2" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="T_jogoGrupo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="selecao" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="AT_1" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="T_grupos">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="grupo"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="T_grupo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="pais" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="tipo" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="T_Bolaocopa">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="grupos"/>
            <xs:element ref="jogoGrupo"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="tipo" type="AT_7"/>
    <xs:attribute name="paisfora" type="AT_2"/>
    <xs:attribute name="paiscasa" type="AT_2"/>
    <xs:attribute name="golf" type="AT_5"/>
    <xs:attribute name="golc" type="AT_3"/>
    <xs:element name="selecao" type="T_selecao"/>
    <xs:element name="pontos" type="T_pontos"/>
    <xs:element name="pais" type="T_pais"/>
    <xs:element name="jogoGrupo" type="T_jogoGrupo"/>
    <xs:element name="grupos" type="T_grupos"/>
    <xs:element name="grupo" type="T_grupo"/>
    <xs:element name="Bolaocopa" type="T_Bolaocopa"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kTies"
         match="@paiscasa[../@golc = ../@golf] | @paisfora[../@golc = ../@golf]" 
         use="."/>
  <xsl:key name="kWins"
         match="@paiscasa[../@golc &gt; ../@golf] | @paisfora[../@golf &gt; ../@golc]" 
         use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/Bolaocopa/grupos/grupo/pais">
        <xsl:sort data-type="number"
                  select="count(key('kTies', @id)) + 3 * count(key('kWins', @id))" 
                  order="descending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pais">
    <xsl:variable name="score" 
                  select="count(key('kTies', @id)) + 3 * count(key('kWins', @id))"/>
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(text(), ' - ', $score)"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result, when run on your sample XML is:

```
<div>
    <p>Dinamarca - 9</p>
    <p>Uruguai - 6</p>
    <p>Franca - 1</p>
    <p>Senegal - 1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work, I'm using xslt 2.0, and also the result should be

Dinamarca - 9
Uruguai - 6
Franca - 1
Senegal - 1

Comment: I misread your description of the point values.  I thought a win was 5 points.  That's fixed now.  What do you mean by "It didn't work".

Comment: It doesn't appear this result, I've linked this xsl to the xml but it didn't work. This transformation works on IE?

Comment: What are you using to run the XSLT? I've been testing it in Altova. Are you using it in a browser? There aren't any browsers that support XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Yes, the thing is that is being created another xml (output xml), what I have to change to the transformation appears in a browser? Do you know?

Comment: It has to use only XSLT 1.0 features.  I can try to come up with an XSLT 1.0 approach tomorrow.

Comment: That would be awesome! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I've come up with an XSLT 1.0 approach. Please give it a try.

Comment: Glad to help. Please remember to [mark the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) that worked for you. :)